# How to emulate C# as-operator in Java

Tags: java, casting

There are situations, where it is practical to have a type-cast return a null value instead of throwing a ClassCastException. C# has the `as` operator to do this. Is there something equivalent available in Java so you don't have to explicitly check for the ClassCastException?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Here's an implementation of as, as suggested by @Omar Kooheji:

```
public static <T> T as(Class<T> clazz, Object o){
    if(clazz.isInstance(o)){
        return clazz.cast(o);
    }
    return null;
}

as(A.class, new Object()) --> null
as(B.class, new B())  --> B
```

Comment: Aaron, what if I want to pass a generic type as the clazz parameter to your "as" function?

Comment: self answer... that cant be done in Java because of type erasure

Comment: I like the design of the above function `as`, but it bothers me the fact that the `isInstance` method will be invoked twice, due to the use of the `cast` method of the class `Class`. Internally, this method uses the `IsIsntance` method to check for compatibility between types.  
Nevertheless, we can expect that the JVM may inline the `cast` code inside the given `as` function and after that the Jitter may remove redundant calls to the `IsInstance` method, but we cannot be sure about that.

Answer (score 29):

I'd think you'd have to roll your own:

```
return (x instanceof Foo) ? (Foo) x : null;
```

EDIT: If you don't want your client code to deal with nulls, then you can introduce a [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)

```
interface Foo {
    public void doBar();
}
class NullFoo implements Foo {
    public void doBar() {} // do nothing
}
class FooUtils {
    public static Foo asFoo(Object o) {
        return (o instanceof Foo) ? (Foo) o : new NullFoo();
    }
}
class Client {
    public void process() {
        Object o = ...;
        Foo foo = FooUtils.asFoo(o);
        foo.doBar(); // don't need to check for null in client
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use the `instanceof` keyword in place of C#'s `is`, but there is nothing like `as`.

Example:

```
if(myThing instanceof Foo) {
   Foo myFoo = (Foo)myThing; //Never throws ClassCastException
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the old double cast. Shame Java doesn't have something as elegant as the 'as' operator.

Answer (score 12):

You could write a static utility method like this.  I don't think it's terribly readable, but it's the best approximation of what you're trying to do.  And if you use static imports it wouldn't be too bad in terms of readability.

```
package com.stackoverflow.examples;
public class Utils {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T safeCast(Object obj, Class<T> type) {
        if (type.isInstance(obj)) {
            return (T) obj;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here's a test case that demonstrates how it works (and that it does work.)

```
package com.stackoverflow.examples;
import static com.stackoverflow.examples.Utils.safeCast;
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertNull;

import org.junit.Test;

public class UtilsTest {

    @Test
    public void happyPath() {
        Object x = "abc";
        String y = safeCast(x, String.class);
        assertNotNull(y);
    }

    @Test
    public void castToSubclassShouldFail() {
        Object x = new Object();
        String y = safeCast(x, String.class);
        assertNull(y);
    }

    @Test
    public void castToUnrelatedTypeShouldFail() {
        Object x = "abc";
        Integer y = safeCast(x, Integer.class);
        assertNull(y);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work. isAssignableFrom tests to see whether obj is an instance of a superclass of T. Thus, safeCast(new Object(), A.class).doA() will return a class cast exception, rather than an NPE.

Comment: you're right.  I had the two class objects backwards.  I've edited the answer and it should be correct now.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using
type.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass() instead of
type.isInstance(obj)?

Comment: nope, isInstance works and is more concise.  I originally thought isInstance wouldn't work for instances of subclasses, but it clearly does.  The answer has been updated to use isInstance, Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In java 8 you can also use stream syntax with Optional:

```
Object o = new Integer(1);

Optional.ofNullable(o)
        .filter(Number.class::isInstance)
        .map(Number.class::cast)
        .ifPresent(n -> System.out.print("o is a number"));
```

Answer (score -4):

I'm speculating you could propably creas an as operator

something like

```
as<T,Type> (left, right)  
which evaluates to 
if (typeof(left) == right)
   return (right)left
else
    return null
```

I'm not sure how you'd do it, I'm a c# at the moment and my Java hat has gotten a bit dusty since I left university.

Comment: Concrete type comparison, i.e. `typeof(left) == right` is not what `as` does.