# Is there a form of "type safe" casting in Java?

Tags: java, casting

Suppose I have two classes deriving from a third abstract class:

```
public abstract class Parent{
    public Parent(){
    }
}

public class ChildA extends Parent {
    public ChildA {
    }
}

public class ChildB extends Parent {
    public ChildB {
    }
}
```

In C# I could handle casting in a somewhat type safe manner by doing:

```
ChildA child = obj as ChildA;
```

Which would make child == null if it wasn't a ChildA type object. If I were to do:

```
ChildA child = (ChildA)obj;
```

...in C# this would throw an exception if the type wasn't correct.

So basically, is there a way to to do the first type of casting in Java? Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148828/how-to-emulate-c-sharp-as-operator-in-java

Comment: Apologies. I searched for "type safe casting java". Didn't occur to me to search for "as keyword java".

Comment: And then it blows up with an NPE. ;)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I can't think of a way in the language itself, but you can easily emulate it like this:

```
ChildA child = (obj instanceof ChildA ? (ChildA)obj : null);
```

Comment: What about obj instanceof List<Integer> ? (List<Interger>)obj : null? You can not use instance of for a generic type, because it will disappear at runtime.

Comment: @vajanko You're right, you can't do that with a generic type if you also need to check for type of items.  You could still do `List ? (List)obj : null` - but you'll get compile-time warnings.  The question didn't say anything about generics.

Answer (score 28):

In java 8 you can also use stream syntax with Optional:

```
    Object o = new Integer(1);

    Optional.ofNullable(o)
            .filter(Number.class::isInstance)
            .map(Number.class::cast)
            .ifPresent(n -> System.out.print("o is a number"));
```

Comment: Number.class::cast is f*** amazing! this one's great!

Answer (score 20):

You can use this method which is compatible with all java types :

```
public static <T> T safeCast(Object o, Class<T> clazz) {
    return clazz != null && clazz.isInstance(o) ? clazz.cast(o) : null;
}
```

Example :

```
// A given object obj
Integer i = safeCast(obj, Integer.class);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `instanceof` operator.

```
if(obj instanceof ChildA){
     final ChildA child = (ChildA) obj;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In modern Java you would use

```
if (obj instanceof ChildA childa) {

}
```

which is nearly the same in modern C#

```
if (animal is Dog dog)
{
    // Use dog here
}
```

Comment: And in this case, "modern Java" would be defined as Java 16.

Answer (score 2):

You can always just check first:

```
if (child instanceof ChildA) {
    ChildA child = (ChildA) child;
    // Do stuff.
}
```

Or just make a quick method:

```
public ChildA getInstance(Parent p) {
    if (child instanceof ChildA) {
        return (ChildA) p;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a good way to deal with this is to use generic methods, which is a reusable/safe option as in the following example:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <E> E coerceTo(Object o, Class<E> target) throws IllegalArgumentException {
  if(target.isInstance(o)) return (E)o;
  String msg = "expected "+target.getName()+" but was "+o.getClass().getName();
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
}
```

Note that here, the cast only occurs when safe, and it's correct to add the **suppressWarnings** annotation.

Here's an example of how to call the method:

```
 Object o = 1;
 int a = coerceTo(o, Integer.class);
```