# JUnit Test Case for stmt if (obj == null) return false;

Tags: object, junit, null

I am trying to write a JUnit Test Case for the below Java Code:

```
private java.lang.Object __equalsCalc = null;

public synchronized boolean equals(java.lang.Object obj) {

    if (!(obj instanceof Crop)) 
        return false;
    Crop other = (Crop) obj;
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (this == obj) return true;
    if (__equalsCalc != null) {
        return (__equalsCalc == obj);
    }
}
```

The Test case i wote is below:

```
public void testCrop() {
    Crop cp = new Crop();

    Object obj = false;

    cp.equals(obj);
    assertSame(obj instanceof Crop, false);

}


public void testCrop1() {

    Crop other = (Crop) obj;
    // assertSame(other.equals(obj), true);
    assertEquals(obj, other);
}
```

The test case for `instanceof` is working fine, but while checking `if(obj == null) return false;` the test case is failing:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please clarify your question. How is `obj` defined? What is the failure message of the test? Side notes: using assertSame to test boolean values is not very clean. Use assertTrue() and assertFalse(). There is no need to test for null when you have already tested for instanceof. null is not an instanceof anything. But the most important is: To test the equals method of your class, you should at least call it in the test and verify if the result is what you expect. You don't do that in your tests.

Comment: private java.lang.Object __equalsCalc = null; public synchronized boolean equals(java.lang.Object obj) { if (!(obj instanceof Crop)) return false; Crop other = (Crop) obj; if (obj == null) return false; if (this == obj) return true; if (__equalsCalc != null) { return (__equalsCalc == obj); }

Comment: the test is pass but when i try to code coverage it shows the passed lines in red.(which means not covered).

Comment: Well null isn't an instance of Crop is it! Swap the if statements round. Clearer question would have helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `assertFalse`

```
public void testEqualsNullIsFalse() {
    Crop crop = new Crop();

    assertFalse(crop.equals(null));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Test case has to be something like

```
Crop cp = new Crop();
Object obj = null;

bool expected = false;

assertEquals(expected,cp.equals(obj));
```

NB if you are trying do something like the as operator, have a look at this

[how to emulate as operator in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148828/how-to-emulate-c-sharp-as-operator-in-java)